# Evaluating $\frac{\sin A + \sin B + \sin C}{\cos A + \cos B + \cos C}$ for a triangle with sides $2$, $3$, $4$

Tags: trigonometry

> What is 
>   $$\frac{\sin A + \sin B + \sin C}{\cos A + \cos B + \cos C}$$
>   for a triangle with sides $2$, $3$, and $4$?

One can use Heron's formula to get $\sin A$, etc, and use $\cos A = (b^2+c^2-a^2)/(2bc)$ to get the cosines. But that's lots of calculate.

> Is there a better way to get the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried solving the triangle (with a calculator) and seeing what happened? Such an experiment could shed light on the problem.

Answer (score 8):

There are well-known identities for $\triangle ABC$
with the angles $A,B,C$,
sides $a,b,c$, 
semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$,
area $S$,
radius $r$ of inscribed and 
radius $R$ of circumscribed circles,

\begin{align}
\sin A+\sin B+\sin C
&=\frac\rho{R}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\cos A+\cos B+\cos C
&=\frac{r+R}{R}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

so

\begin{align}
x&=
\frac{\sin A + \sin B + \sin C}{\cos A + \cos B + \cos C}
=\frac{\rho}{r+R}
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}

we also know that

\begin{align} 
R&=\frac{abc}{4S}
,\\
r&=\frac{S}{\rho}
,\\
S&=\tfrac14\sqrt{4(ab)^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)^2}
,\\
\end{align}

thus we can find that for $a=2,b=3,c=4$
\begin{align} 
\rho&=\frac{9}{2}
,\\
S&=\frac{3\sqrt{15}}{4}
,\\
R&=\frac{8\sqrt{15}}{15}
,\\
r&=\frac{\sqrt{15}}{6}
,\\
x&=\frac{\rho}{r+R}
=\frac{3\sqrt{15}}{7}
\approx 1.6598500
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Using an application of the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Statement), we get
$$
\begin{align}
2R\sin(A)=a\tag{1a}\\
2R\sin(B)=b\tag{1b}\\
2R\sin(C)=c\tag{1c}
\end{align}
$$
where $R$ is the radius of the [circumcircle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle).

Furthermore, with $s=\frac{a+b+c}2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Area}
&=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\tag2\\[3pt]
&=\frac12bc\sin(A)\tag3\\
&=\frac{abc}{4R}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)
$(3)$: triangular area given by [Cross Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Geometric_meaning)
$(4)$: apply $\text{(1a)}$ to $(3)$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C)
&=\frac{a+b+c}{2R}\tag5\\
&=\frac{4s\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{abc}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(5)$: apply $\text{(1a)}$, $\text{(1b)}$, and $\text{(1c)}$
$(6)$: get $R=\frac{abc}{4\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}$ from $(2)$ and $(4)$

The Law of Cosines says
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(A)&=\frac{b^2a+c^2a-a^3}{2abc}\tag{7a}\\
\cos(C)&=\frac{c^2b+a^2b-b^3}{2abc}\tag{7b}\\
\cos(C)&=\frac{a^2c+b^2c-c^3}{2abc}\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$
Adding these and factoring yields
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)
&=\frac{(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)}{2abc}+1\tag8\\
&=\frac{4(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}{abc}+1\tag9
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(6)$ and $(9)$ gives
$$
\frac{\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C)}{\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)}=\frac{4s\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}}{4(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)+abc}\tag{10}
$$

---

Plugging $(a,b,c)=(2,3,4)$ into $(10)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(A)+\sin(B)+\sin(C)}{\cos(A)+\cos(B)+\cos(C)}
&=\frac{4\cdot\frac92\sqrt{\frac92\cdot\frac52\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac12}}{4\cdot\frac52\cdot\frac32\cdot\frac12+2\cdot3\cdot4}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{15}}{7}\tag{11}
\end{align}
$$